# Videos Post Type with Custom Filters

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, videos

Basically, I am trying to achieve exactly same as in this link: https://www.fitnessblender.com/videos

In my WordPress site, the first thing I did was creating a post type 'videos'. I am not sure whether I should create custom meta or taxonomies to be used for the filtering. What is the best practice to make same as that page?

Comment: looks like taxonomy

Comment: You mean all of the filters should be taxonomy?

Comment: Yes.  I'm saying that site is filtering on taxonomy.

Comment: Ok then, I will set them all up as taxonomy. But what about calories and video duration? Shouldn't be set as custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

By this website , https://www.fitnessblender.com/videos 
Taken out the first portion (e.g Difficulty) - Make this as Taxonomy/Category,
Then the  below filter checkboxes (e.g 1,2,3)- this will be Tags,
Custom post type - videos